# Alternative to MS Excel for non-calculating (text & images) tables

Tags: project-management, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

In my company and in probably thousands of other companies, Excel is misused for word processing (creation of tables containing mainly text, for example project plans and lists of all sorts), basically because no one knows an alternative, or because people can't be bothered to use the tables function in Word.

Excel is totally unsuitable for this because of its awkward and limited text editing functions. The worst is however that you can't easily insert images into cells, as you can in Word tables, for example.

Therefore, project plans, lists, tables and the likes created in Excel tend to be mostly awful and everyone hates them: they look awful, they are awful to use, edit and present, they are fiddly, they don't contain images and graphics, etc. pp.

Does anyone know of an alternative program, with the following features:

- easy handling of tables (of basically unlimited size -- what MS Word can't do)
- easy insertion of images **into** cells like in Word
- focus on word processing rather than math/calculation

I am aware that Google Sheets has most of these features, however I'm rather looking for a "mainstream" installable program for the typical Office user.

Comment: I know those Excel tables. Are you sure they don't need calculation features? The ones I saw heavily relied on macros.

Comment: No, these company Excel tables in my experience almost always are d*mb and contain only text and some inept images floating around. People just use Excel because they don't know of another way of quickly puzzling something together in two (unlimited) dimensions with a grid to hold things in place, sort of.